# How can I alter a system design to improve computational efficiency with AWS?

Tags: architecture, machine-learning, computer-architecture

I have a use case which will take in data from the front end and transform it with various parameters. Then a random effects model is run on each transformation and multiple models are built

For example: Data has 5 independent variables. For each independent variable there are around 3 consecutive transformations to be made and each has around 10 possible values of transformation. The entire space or combination will be (10^3)^5. But we will just give smaller subset of values for transformation and modelling, think of it as similar to grid search. So around 10k models will be built per user.

Now the problem I'm facing is on how to scale this system to multiple users. AWS server with 64 gigs RAM and 8 cores bogs down significantly with just two users(given the current system is horrible with a monolithic design).

I'm a noob to most of this so the solution I could come up with is:

Break up the server into 3, one for application, pre processing and modelling. This would separate the load and we can allocate compute intensive instances to modelling alone. If its an acceptable solution I still would love to know how to scale cheaply by design rather than adding more ec2s and cores(have a docker image for each flask server).

How would you go about the modelling server; treat it as a function and send api calls to it with the relevant data and make models one by one or in some kind of batches? I'm hoping WSGI(gunicorn) server can be configured to have multiple workers so that'll solve running multiple models in parallel.

And mongo db is used to save the results. Now mongo db apparently writes one at a time so is there seems to be a bottleneck there.(If this fact is wrong, let me try getting the source)

Would lambda or sagemaker come in handy for automatic scaling of the modelling part?

Also please let me know of any design or factual mistakes here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The first thing you ought to do is find a way to measure the performance of your components, so that you can determine where the bottlenecks actually are.  You can then focus your efforts on those aspects specifically.  "Scalability" is not necessarily your problem if the system is bogging down at only two users.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple key concepts in here that will limit your ability to scale:

- Monolithic design
- Combinatoric set of artifacts per user
- Serialized updates to database

Of those, the first two are the most costly.  Tools like Sagemaker allow you to create models.  The most compute intensive part of the process is training those models with your data.  Once you've trained your model, you can deploy it and use that trained model for the live system.  Usually it uses far fewer resources to run a trained model.

There's a few things I recommend:

- Split the monolithic design if possible so you can create a processing pipeline
- Use temporary storage like Redis to store intermediate results until you are ready to store finished products
- Use a message queue like Rabbit or Kafka to push processing to the next stage in the pipeline (look at Apache NiFi or Spring Cloud Data Flow to model the pipeline itself)
- Leverage GPUs for parallel processing if at all possible.  AWS has EC2 instances with GPU available and some machine learning algorithms work much faster in GPUs
- Attempt to batch save your results to your permanent data store (i.e. Mongo in this case)

Another thing to consider is using a managed instance of MondoDB.  The Mongo team were really advertising that service at AWS re:Invent 2019.  It allows them to worry about scaling and backing up the Mongo cluster and you to worry about how you use it.

I mentioned Apache NiFi and Spring Cloud Data Flow above.  What they allow you to do is specify your workflow, and they will manage moving messages from one step to the next.  They can also manage your container instances so that only the processing steps that need to be scaled will be.  And when the demand is over, the extra containers will be reclaimed.

I believe AWS has some support for pipelines as well, using Lambda functions to route work.

Last concern here is the terms of service you are trying to support.  If the models you are building are expected to take a long time, you can serialize the processing somewhat.  If processing one user at a time is within acceptable limits, then attempt to interleave requests so that by the end the processing stays within acceptable limits but you get your users satisfied as soon as you can.  You'll still probably need some more capacity, but you might be able to service more users on the same amount of hardware.

As far as automatic scaling, you are looking at a couple technologies:

- If you are containerized, Kubernetes lets you set policies to automatically scale pods (containers) up and down depending on demand.  There are several advanced features to target certain containers for specific processing nodes
- AWS Auto Scaling will perform a similar function at the EC2 instance level.  Combine it with Cloud Formation (infrastructure as code) and you have a very robust autoscaling system in place without containers.

What's not clear here is if you are generating learning models for your customers, or running models you already have against customer data.  There are significant details that change in your architecture depending on the answer to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a swift reply. The service I'm trying to implement is to make models for users.